# UI is not updated immediately, only after second attempt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

This is `html`:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in controller.users">
    <p>{{user.name}}</p>
    <button ng-click="controller.deleteUser(user)" value="delete"></button>
</div>
```

This is `controller`:

```
vm = this;
vm.users;

activate();

function activate() {
    service.getUserList().then(function(userList){
        vm.users = userList;
    });
}

function deleteUser() {
    service.deleteUser(user).then(function(){
        activate();
    });
}
```

This is `service`:

```
function deleteUser(user) {
    var index = userList.indexOf(user);
    if (index !== -1) userList.splice(index, 1);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(userList);
    });
}
```

So, I delete a user, it then talks to `service` and when done, activates `activate()`. This updates `vm.users`, but not in UI. On the second click of `delete`, it works though!

What's going on here?

Comment: It is likely not triggering the digest cycle. Is `service.getUserList()` using the `$ajax` service? if not, angular does not know to trigger the digest cycle upon completion of the `.then()` - only on return from the parent function (which is immediate)

Comment: @mhodges, I added `service`. It is mocked, no AJAX.

Comment: Ahh, use `$q` service for deferreds/promises in angularjs, that's your issue. The API is almost identical to that of `Promise` so you shouldn't have to change any of your code. Just change `new Promise(...)` to `$q(...)`

Comment: AngularJs doesn't know to trigger the digest cycle on normal promises, whereas that trigger is built into the `$q` and `$http` services under the covers

Comment: @mhodges, no luck. I updated code above.

Comment: @mhodges you mean `$http`, not `$ajax`

Comment: @Phil Derp, yes. haha it's been a while /facepalm

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho no you haven't. You're still using `new Promise` instead of `$q`

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho Did you make sure to properly inject the `$q` service into your service?

Comment: I did now, and it worked. Thanks @mhodges! Please put as answer.

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho Done.

Comment: Some guy downgraded, then commented, then removed comment after my reply, but forgot to upgrade back. Dude, get back!

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho The question did have quite a bit of missing information at the start. After the edits, it is looking much better. I will offset the early downvote

Comment: @mhodges, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**: Your issue is that AngularJs does not know to trigger the digest cycle upon completion of the .then() from non-angular promises. It only knows to trigger it on the return from the parent function (which is immediate, so no change has happened yet).

*side note* - that is why it works on the 2nd click, because it will trigger on the immediate return from the function, at which time the data has changed from the first click.

**Solution**: If you use the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service for deferreds/promises in angularjs, that will solve your issue. The API is almost identical to that of `Promise` so you shouldn't have to change any of your code. Just change `new Promise(...)` to `$q(...)`